# Segment fault on strcat

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

There is a Segment fault on my code but I really cant't figure out the reason.

```
char *cord_tostring(cord_t R) {
    if (R == NULL)
        return NULL;
    char *str = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10000);
    if (R->left == NULL && R->right == NULL)
        return R->data;
    strcat(str, cord_tostring(R->left));
    strcat(str, cord_tostring(R->right));
    return str;
}
```

where

```
typedef struct cord_node *cord_t;
typedef struct cord_node cord;
struct cord_node {
    int len;
    cord *left;
    cord *right;
    char *data;
};
```

Comment: How big is your tree?

Comment: try `*str = 0;` before `strcat`.

Comment: Also show how you call your function `cord_tostring`

Comment: On a side note - it's always a good idea to memset to 0 (NULL) all the bytes after an allocation:-
`memset(str, 0, sizeof(char)*10000);`

Comment: @Zakir Or use `calloc()`, which returns an array set to zeroes.

Comment: @Zakir 't's always a good idea to memset to 0 (NULL) all the bytes after an allocation' no, it just isn't.

Comment: @Zakir: if you want full initialization to all bits zero, use `calloc()`. Using `memset()` produces more code, is less efficient and is error prone.

Comment: per the C standard, the expression `sizeof(char)` is always 1.  multiplying anything by 1 has no effect. so that expression in the parameter to `malloc()` just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc. Suggest removing that expression

Comment: when allocating jheap memory for some struct,  it is best to set any pointer fields to NULL.  That was not done in the posted code and begs the question, was it done in the code that created the passed in parameter `R` tree?

Comment: Note: every pass through the function: `cord_tostring()` allocates another 10000 bytes from the heap.  Probably NOT what you want to do.

Comment: If the fields of `R` `left` and `rightl` are both NULL, then there is a memory leak because 'str' is not passed to `free()`  Suggest moving the call to `malloc` to after the statement: `return R->data`

Comment: what happens if only one of the two fields 'R->left` or `R->right` is NULL,?    Then the call to `strcat()` has a parameter of NULL  This will cause a seg fault event.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score 2):

There are many problems in your code:

- You do not check if `malloc()` succeeded. On many systems, `malloc()` can fail and return `NULL`. Such failures should be tested and reported instead of invoking undefined behavior.
- The block allocated by `malloc()` is uninitialized: calling `strcat()` with it as a destination has undefined behavior. You should initialize its first byte to `'\0'` or use `strcpy()` instead of `strcat()`.
- You test if both `R->left` and `R->right` are `NULL before recursing, but if only one of the is`NULL`, you will be calling`strcat()`with a`NULL` source pointer.
- You do not free the pointer allocated for each node, causing massive memory leakage, eventually leading to memory allocation failure or worse.
- You concatenate all `data` fields without any separator. This might be the intended behavior or not depending of your goal.

Here is a corrected version, using space as a separator:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *cord_tostring(cord_t R) {
    if (R == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (R->left == NULL && R->right == NULL)
        return R->data ? strdup(R->data) : NULL;

    char *s1 = cord_tostring(R->left);
    char *s2 = cord_tostring(R->right);
    if (s1 == NULL)
        return s2;
    if (s2 == NULL)
        return s1;

    char *s = malloc(strlen(s1) + 1 + strlen(s2) + 1);
    if (s == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failure\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    sprintf(s, "%s %s", s1, s2);
    free(s1);
    free(s2);
    return s;
}
```

Note that the return value of `cord_to_string()` should be freed after use.

Comment: @OzgurMurat: returning `""` is a problem: the return value should always be allocated or the caller cannot determine whether to free it or not.  Testing for `NULL` is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

`strcat` wants a NUL terminated string

> The strcat() function shall append a copy of the string pointed to by
>   s2 (including the terminating NUL character) to the end of the string
>   pointed to by s1. **The initial byte of s2 overwrites the NUL
>   character at the end of s1.** If copying takes place between objects
>   that overlap, the behavior is undefined.

Change to

```
char *str = malloc(10000);
str[0] = '\0';
```

or better yet (as pointed out by @EugeneSh in comments) use `strcpy`, it doesn't needs a NUL terminator

```
strcpy(str,cord_tostring(R->left));
strcat(str,cord_tostring(R->right));
```

Comment: I would rather replace first `strcat` with `strXcpy`.... And add `free` after each recursive call.

Comment: `str[0] = '\0';` can be simply `str[0] = 0;`.

Comment: @i486: both statements are equivalent, but the first is preferable as it conveys extra information.  `NULL` and `0` are also equivalent in many cases, but using `NULL` is a more explicit spelling for the null pointer.

Comment: @chqrlie `NULL` can be something different from 0. But `'\0'` is always `0` and there is no extra information - only extra characters and worse readability.

Comment: @i486: extra characters do not necessarily lessen readability: extra spaces around operators and proper indentation actually improve readability.  Whether `0` or `'\0'` is more readable in this context is a matter of taste and local conventions. I personally favor the latter, but you obviously differ. That's OK.  What is more important is consistency. Another case for simplification is `sizeof(char) * 10000` that is by definition the same as `10000` except for the type.

Comment: @i486m your suggestion to use `0` is not really correct.  Now, the implicit conversion feature will save you, but know that a 0 *(an integer of 4 or 8 bytes is not the same as a single char '\0'